# Chained Select2 whith ajax json values

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

Have some problems to populate a Select2 with json data retrieved by ajax.

I check all samples from [Select2-Github-AjaxData](http://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) and other from StackOverFlow so always have same problem... the Json retrieved can't update next select2.

Some tries i use Jquery.Ajax to retrieve and assign:

```
    function loadvariedad() {
    var productIDVal= $("#frb_producto").val();
    $.ajax ({
    url: "http://www.fruitbull.info/api/json/es/v",
    data: {idv: productIDVal, key:"123456"},
    delay: 250,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(theResponse) {
        $("#frb_variedad").select2({
              data: theResponse.items
            });
    }
    });
};
```

Other solution checked was the sample on Github form Ajax:

```
var productIDVal= $("#frb_producto").val();
$('#frb_variedad').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'http://www.fruitbull.info/api/json/es/v?key=123&idv='+productIDVal,
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Any idea or help to check?

[My sample and tries on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mastercafe/cyk48Lpz/)

Solved by json origin data was formatted incorrectly

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Just now solved.. the problem was on JSON supplied externally, i read [{id:1,text:'value-text'},etc... and change to [{"id":1,"text":"value-text"} and now run perfect.